# How to know if a custom ROM uses existing swap partition

Tags: custom-roms, swap

Recently I switched my custom ROM installed on my HTC Desire to a 4.1.2 based ROM (PARANOIDANDROID based).

The ROM works fine but sometimes the device has serious lag of several seconds. I assume that this may be caused by a SWAP partition I created once on my SD-card but that was never used by my previous ROMs.

How can I find out if the SWAP partition is used or not?

Comment: I'd open a terminal app and execute the `mount` command. In order to be used, a partition needs to be mounted. If this is true for the swap partition, the output should include a line with "swap" (as partition type) AFAIK.

Comment: @Izzy: The mount list does not show a swap partition but free show swap used. Therefore the mount command is not a working solution.

Comment: Yeah, I saw this when I checked it at another device. When I wrote my comment, I only had my phone with me (no swap there), so I couldn't tell. After verification, I wrote below answer -- which fits :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply get yourself a terminal app (a good choice would be [Android Terminal Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm)), start it, and enter the command `free`. The output then should look like this:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers
Mem:        487344     474312      13032          0      42224
-/+ buffers:           432088      55256
Swap:             0          0         0
```

This example is from my *Motorola Milestone 2*, and you can see: it does *not* use any swap: "total" available swap space is "0". If your device would use swap, at least the numbers for "totals" and one of "used" or "free" should be > 0.

Comment: Thanks I can see that I was right - swap total/used 31740.

Comment: Which means: full O.o You could try playing with the "swappiness" to improve that -- but that's a different question (but a valid one, so you could ask it :)